# Capturing current frame using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to capture frame from my camera when the specific event occurs

my code

```
    import cv2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.43.1:8080/video") 
    if int(data) < 45:
        return_value, image = cap.read()
        cv2.imwrite('Images/'+str(count)+'.png', image)
        print("capture")
```

But its saving older frames when it capture please help i want current frame to be saved

Comment: What is `data`?  how are you handling the "event"?

Comment: Data is data coming from COM port from ultrasonic distance sensor  and if distance is less then 45 I have to capture image

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the frames as they arrive otherwise they just buffer up. You discard the frames you don't want. The following should demonstrate this:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.43.1:8080/video") 
while True:
    return_value, image = cap.read()
    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
    if int(data) < 45:
        cv2.imwrite('Images/'+str(count)+'.png', image)
        print("capture")
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: No its not working its capturing older frames